# How can I filter multiple node IDs at the same time using exposed filters?

Tags: 6, views

I have an view with an exposed filer for node IDs, which seems to only accept a single value.

Is there a way to filter nodes giving more than a node ID?
I tried `1 and 2`, `1,2`, and `1 2`, but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this can be done using only the Views module.

You must create a custom module that implements `hook_views_query_alter()`. (The code is for Drupal 7.)

```php
function my_module_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->current_display == 'my_current_display' && $view->exposed_raw_input['nid']) {
    $nids = explode(',', $view->exposed_raw_input['nid']);
 
    foreach ($nids as $nid) {
      $query->where[1]['conditions'][] = array(
        'field' => 'node.nid',
        'value' => $nid,
        'operator' => '!=',
      );
    }
  }
}
```

I found this solution on [How to Pass Multiple Values through an Exposed Filter in Drupal Views](https://www.metaltoad.com/blog/how-pass-multiple-values-through-exposed-filter-drupal-views). Credits go to  Peter Schuelke, who wrote that article on October 17, 2012.

Answer (score 0):

In views context filter settings is a section where you can enable multiple value splitting, e.g.: 1+2+3 (for OR) or 1,2,3 (for AND)

Comment: Does that work for Drupal 6?